Netplan apply breaks with AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'CSafeLoader'
I am running a DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
which was originally created by Hetzner
netplan info gives:
netplan.io:
features:

auth-phase2
dhcp-use-domains
ipv6-mtu
generated-supplicant
website: https://netplan.io/

apt list:
netplan.io/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 0.99-0ubuntu3~18.04.5 amd64 [installed]
Did anyone find a solution to this problem?
Many thanks!!!

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.
